# set a common color bar for subplot

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

I am going to plot a numpy array by plt module. I have no idea how I can just have a one shared color bar for my subplot. Or even if it plots with two, I would like to clim it to just plot in the range of (-0.4-0.4) for both colorbars.

Thanks all
Here is my codes:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10, 10))

im1 = ax1.imshow(input[:,:,141],cmap = 'Spectral_r')
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(im1, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')

im2 = ax2.imshow(out_put[:,:,141], cmap = 'Spectral_r')
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(im2, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
ax1.set_title('Input', fontsize = 16)
ax2.set_title('Output of model', fontsize = 16)
ax2.set_axis_off()
ax1.set_axis_off()


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call `colorbar` once, and pass both `ax1,ax2` to `ax`. For the `clim` option, my matplotlib says that `cb.set_clim` is deprecated. It might be better to pass `vmin,vmax` to `imshow`:

```
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(13, 5))

im1 = ax1.imshow(np.random.uniform(-1,1, size=(10,10)),
                 vmin=-0.4, vmax=0.4,
                 cmap = 'Spectral_r')

im2 = ax2.imshow(np.random.uniform(-1,1, size=(10,10)), 
                 vmin=-0.4, vmax=0.4,
                 cmap = 'Spectral_r')

cb = fig.colorbar(im2, ax=(ax1, ax2), orientation='vertical')
cb.set_clim(-0.4,0.4)
```

Output:

[image]